# How to choose whether to persist or discard changes in HDF5 file before closing

Tags: python, hdf5, h5py, pytables

I'd like to manipulate a set of data in an `hdf5` file and be able to decide, before closing the file, whether to discard every changes or not.
From the doc of [File drivers](https://docs.h5py.org/en/stable/high/file.html#file-drivers):

> HDF5 ships with a variety of different low-level drivers, which map
> the logical HDF5 address space to different storage mechanisms. You
> can specify which driver you want to use when the file is opened:
>
> ```
> f = h5py.File('myfile.hdf5', driver=<driver name>, <driver_kwds>)
> ```
>
> For example, the HDF5 “core” driver can be used to create a purely
> in-memory HDF5 file, optionally written out to disk when it is closed.
> Here’s a list of supported drivers and their options:
>
> - ‘core’:
>
>   Store and manipulate the data in memory, and optionally write it back out when the file is closed. Using this with an existing file and
>   a reading mode will read the entire file into memory. Keywords:
>
>   - backing_store:
>
>     If True (default), save changes to the real file at the specified path on close() or flush(). If False, any changes are
>     discarded when the file is closed.

Regardless whether I perform a call to `flush()` or not, changes are always discarded (as expected). While, opening with default driver, changes are always persisted to the file on closure.

Based on what above, I've just created a very simple example:

```py
from h5py import File



# Create a dummy file from scratch
f = File('test.h5', 'w')
f.create_dataset("test_dataset", data=[1, 2, 3])
f.close()



# Open and modify the data
f = File('test.h5', 'r+')  # In this case changes are always persisted
# f = File('test.h5', 'r+', driver='core', backing_store=False)  # In this case changes are always discarded
ds = f["test_dataset"]
ds[...] = [3, 4, 5]
# f.flush()  # Useless in this case, obviously
f.close()  # Here changes should be discarded



# Read now `test_dataset`
f = File('test.h5', 'r')
print(f['test_dataset'][...])
f.close()
```

Is there a way to decide just before closing the file whether to save changes or not?

### EDIT 1: PyTables `undo` mechanism seems to work ONLY with newly created dataset, NOT with editing of pre-existing ones

```py
import tables as t
import numpy as np

# Create the file
with t.open_file(r'test.h5', 'w') as fr:
    fr.create_carray('/', 'TestArray', obj=np.array([1, 2, 3], dtype='uint8'))

with t.open_file('test.h5', 'r+') as fr:
    # This will remove any previously created marks
    if fr.is_undo_enabled():
        fr.disable_undo()
    fr.enable_undo()  # Re-enable undo
    fr.mark('MyMark')

    # Create new array from scratch, and it will be discarded
    new_arr = fr.create_carray('/', 'NewCreatedArray', obj=np.array([10, 11, 12]))

    # Modify a pre-existing array! --> THIS WILL NOT BE DISCARDED
    arr = fr.root.TestArray
    arr[...] = np.array([3, 4, 5])

    # Move back to when I opened the file
    fr.undo('MyMark')

with t.open_file('test.h5', 'r+') as fr:
    print(fr)
    print('Test Array: ', fr.root.TestArray[:])
```

Result is:

```
test.h5 (File) ''
Last modif.: '2023-05-18T07:26:13+00:00'
Object Tree: 
/ (RootGroup) ''
/TestArray (CArray(3,)) ''

Test Array:  [3 4 5]
```

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do that with the core driver and backing store option. PyTables has a method to enable undo/redo file operations. However, I don't think h5py has that feature.

Comment: What is the workflow is that requires this behavior? Why not use the standard file  driver, and create NumPy arrays of the data you may (or may not) want to add to the file? Then before you close the file, you can save the data as needed. h5py dataset objects behave like numpy arrays, so there's not much difference in the code (and probably a lower memory footprint since you aren't reading the whole file into RAM).

Comment: There are a couple of reasons. I work with numpy arrays, actually, the list in the example is just a very quick object only for demonstration. Problem is that I may end up working on big hdf5 data, and at the end of some data analysis and conditioning, I want the user to be able to decide whether to save the changes or discard everything and leave the file as it was before opening it.

Comment: The alternative is to load the entire file in memory and to rewrite it after changes in case the user wants to, but, sure you know, this might be computationally heavy, above all if the user wants to perform several saves before exiting.

Comment: If you are working with very large files, you may hit memory limits if you load the entire file in memory. (That's the whole point of HDF5 -- to access data from disk and NOT load everything into memory). I added an answer using PyTables that you might find interesting.

Answer (score 2):

As noted in my comments, PyTables has the ability to mark, undo, and redo the database status. I created 2 examples to show different processes. Print  statements are provided to show what happens in each example.

1. The 1st example shows how to undo a newly created data set. It creates a file with an array dataset ('test0'). Next a mark is set, and a 2nd array
   dataset ('test1') is added, followed by undo. Then a 2nd mark is set and a 3rd dataset('test2') is created (but undo not called).
2. The 2nd example is a followup to @Buzz's comments on May 18, 2023. It shows the process to modify the values of an existing dataset (as an extension of the code added to the question). It creates a file with an array dataset ('TestArray'). Next a mark is set, and the 1st array dataset is renamed ('TestArray_bck'). Then a 2nd dataset is created using the same name as the 1st, but with new data values. After undo is called, the file reverts to the status before the mark.

Note: `enable_undo` is persistent in the file. So, you can reopen the file with `mode='r+'`, enter `h5f.undo("test2")`, and changes back to mark `"test2"` will be undone.

**Example 1**

```
import tables as tb

# Create a dummy file from scratch
with tb.File('test_tb.h5', 'w') as h5f:
    h5f.create_array("/","test0", obj=[1, 2, 3])

# Open, enable undo and modify the data 
# Set mark, add data, then undo; changes are discarded
with tb.File('test_tb.h5', 'r+')as h5f:
    h5f.enable_undo()
    h5f.mark("test1") # mark name optional
    h5f.create_array("/","test1", obj=[11, 12, 13])
    print("\n*** Before Undo ***")
    for node in h5f.iter_nodes('/'):
        print(node._v_pathname)
    h5f.undo("test1")
    print("\n*** After Undo ***")
    for node in h5f.iter_nodes('/'):
        print(node._v_pathname)
    
# Open and modify the data
# Set mark, add data, do not undo; changes are saved
with tb.File('test_tb.h5', 'r+')as h5f:
    h5f.mark("test2") # mark name optional
    h5f.create_array("/","test2", obj=[21, 22, 23])

with tb.File('test_tb.h5', 'r')as h5f:
    print("\n*** Final ***")
    for node in h5f.iter_nodes('/'):
        print(node._v_pathname)
        print(node[:])
```

**Example 2**

```
import tables as t
import numpy as np

# Create the file
with t.open_file(r'test_tb2.h5', 'w') as fr:
    fr.create_carray('/', 'TestArray', obj=np.array([1, 2, 3], dtype='uint8'))
    print(fr)
    print('Test Array: ', fr.root.TestArray[:],'\n')
    
with t.open_file('test_tb2.h5', 'r+') as fr:
    # This will remove any previously created marks
    if fr.is_undo_enabled():
        fr.disable_undo()
    fr.enable_undo()  # Re-enable undo
    fr.mark('MyMark')

    # Rename pre-existing array! --> Undo works on this
    fr.rename_node('/', 'TestArray_bck', name='TestArray')
    # Create a new array dataset using the previous name
    fr.create_carray('/', 'TestArray', obj=np.array([3, 4, 5], dtype='uint8'))

    print(fr)
    print('Test Array: ', fr.root.TestArray[:],'\n')
    
    # Move back to when I opened the file
    fr.undo('MyMark')
    print(fr)
    print('Test Array: ', fr.root.TestArray[:],'\n')
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that is a viable solution. I didn't know anything about pytables. It's a pity that it is not a drop in replacement of h5py, meaning that many calls are to be refactored. However, the biggest problem, just pour parler, seems to be the lack of SWMR support.

Comment: Yeah, not a drop-in replacement, but in my experience PyTables has a matching method for every h5py method. (And it has some handy methods the h5py doesn't have.)  Dataset creation is a little more complicated b/c PyTables has multiple '`create_xxx()'` methods depending on the data type (homogeneous vs heterogeneous) and storage options (compression, resizing). I don't think PyTables supports SWMR, but it supports multiple read access processes if you aren't writing to the file (NWMR ?).

Comment: Sorry, reading the do/undo mechanism I gave it for granted that this solution would have worked. Actually I'm just realising that it works only with newly created dataset, as you proposed, but it is significantly different from my question example. Please, have a look to the edited part of the question

Comment: Yeah, I didn't test your scenario (overwriting data in an existing dataset). Clearly the Mark/Undo mechanism doesn't catch that. :-( I found a way to get this to work with your process using the `File.rename_node()`method. Basically, I rename the node with the exiting data to a "backup" name, and load the data into an array with the desired name. Undo will remove the newly created array and undo rename operation. I will add that to my previous answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not convinced that this is the best approach as it will drive up your memory requirements. Possible alternatives are

- working on a copy of the file, preferably on a file system with copy-on-write support
- recording changes separately (possibly with a temporary file as buffer), then applying them to the file at the end
- switching to a different storage that supports transactions

Anyway, one thing you can do is work on a `BytesIO` buffer. This mimics the "core" driver but gives you full control about when to write the buffer back to file.

```py
import io
import h5py

with open("foo.h5", "rb") as infile:
    raw = infile.read()
buf = io.BytesIO(raw)
del raw
with h5py.File(buf, "a") as memfile:
    memfile.create_dataset("bar", data=np.random.random((100, 100)))
with open("foo.h5", "wb") as outfile:
    outfile.write(buf.getbuffer())
```